# How to debug c# code called from R by rClr?

Tags: c#, .net, r, visual-studio, rclr

I'm trying to debug C# methods that are called from R by means of [rClr](https://r2clr.codeplex.com/). In the VS-project I have set the the start action property to start Rscript.exe with the R-script as commandline parameter.  (Similar to what you would do e.g. to debug c# functions called from Excel using [ExcelDNA](https://excel-dna.net/).) The R-script runs as expected, but execution doesn't stop at the breakpoints. So I'm not able to do any debugging from Visual Studio.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a minimal example:

**C#-code in VS-project RLib1 - Calculates.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RLib1
{
    public class Calculate {
        public static double Sum(double x1, double x2) {
            return x1 + x2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Properties in RLib1.csproj**

Start external program: c:\R\R-3.3.2\bin\Rscript.exe

Command line arguments: c:\VSProjects\RLib1\TestRLib1.R

**R-script in TestRLib1.R**

```
library(rClr)
clrLoadAssembly('C:/VSProjects/RLib1/RLib1/bin/Debug/RLib1.dll')
clrGetTypesInAssembly("RLib1")
clrCallStatic("RLib1.Calculate","Sum",2,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the "Attach to process" feature of visual studio as it is a bit more transparent in terms of debugging behavior; see https://github.com/jmp75/rClr/issues/32 for details.